# From which NASA publication originates/where can I find a higher resolution version of this SSME flow diagram?

Tags: nasa, propulsion, reference-request, ssme

This came up when I was taking a look at Endeavour over in LA. Where can I find a readable version of this full flow diagram (valves, control systems, and everything)?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's on pdf pages 139-141 here: https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/KSC-SSME_System_Eng_Handbook.pdf  but you'll have to "glue" it together into one drawing. Fully legible though.

Here's a snippet at high resolution

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! I knew you were the man for this one :)

Comment: @AntonHengst check out drawing 10.13 here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/shuttleultra/files/References/JSC-1117%20-%20Space_Shuttle_Systems_Handbook_Vol2.pdf/download This is the booster flight controller drawing

Comment: Are there any copyright issues in re-uploading a full glued-together version here?

Comment: Wow, what a find. ...also, what a URL.

Comment: Get out your crayons; this one begs to be color-coded.

Comment: @leftaroundabout if you do, let me know!

Comment: @kerlyn https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/56187/from-which-nasa-publication-originates-where-can-i-find-the-color-version-of-thi

Answer (score 3):

OK ... So the MPS / SSME system was what I worked on a LOOOOONG time ago, feel free to ask questions. My only request for @Anton Hengst is can you get the Shuttle URL to the Endeavour Docents so that they have the information?:
https://aka.ms/space_shuttle

@leftaroundabout The color version:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/ssme_block1.jpg

https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/ssme_block1_2.jpg

https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/SSME_Block1_3.jpg

There are no copyright issues @leftaroundabout, feel free to do so. Your tax dollars paid for every penny of the cost of this program.

Comment: This is really the answer to this question https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56187/6944 which asks for a color version.