# From which NASA publication originates/where can I find the color version of this SSME flow diagram?

Tags: engine-design, ssme, itar, aerojet-rocketdyne

Sorry to ask [such a similar question as the last one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/56171/from-which-nasa-publication-originates-where-can-i-find-a-higher-resolution-vers), but I already marked that one as answered. My friend who works at the Endeavour exhibit in LA found this diagram left on the ground after a gentleman from Rocketdyne came in to look at their testbed SSME on display.

He insists that it does not exist in the public domain due to it being labeled Aerojet Rocketdyne proprietary. I'm pretty sure it's got to, as at least the engines are owned by NASA (even if the design isn't (?)). If is it not in the public domain, how and why? If so, where can I find it?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Just for clarification, I'm all but sure this is simply a color version of the same diagram in the linked photo.

Comment: Links to a color version were posted in an answer to the other question, here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57786/6944

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found in the wild. This isn't a quality image but goes to show that.

[image]

[Source](https://twitter.com/nolarobert/status/697269350936481794/photo/1) (twitter)

Buy it at auction [here](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-nasa-space-shuttle-main-3846292578)! (no affiliation)

As far as a document goes, more modern versions of the [SSME System Engineer Handbook](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/KSC-SSME_System_Eng_Handbook.pdf) referenced in the answer to the linked question contain a color version of the drawing. They have titles like *Space Shuttle Main Engine Flight Operations Handbook [Orbiter-name] [Mission-number]* – for example, *Endeavour STS-127* No document number though.

Comment: Hmm. Any ideas where to start searching for the digital source?

Comment: @AntonHengst the more modern versions of the *SSME Systems Engineer Handbook* linked in the answer to the other question have the color version of the drawing. But I have not found one of those modern versions on the internet. Updated title is *Space Shuttle Main Engine Flight Operations Handbook [Orbiter-name] [Mission-number]*

Comment: @AntonHengst ok! Please report back if you obtain one.

Answer (score 4):

So ... @AntonHengst I have ALL kinds of versions on color and non-color SSME diagrams. Request from you, can you pass the Space Shuttle link to your LA Endeavour Docent friend? I have tried to send this to them to no avail:
https://gandalf.azureedge.net/shuttle.html

The design and diagrams were paid for by Tax dollars so they are not copyright. I used to work on the MPS / SSME subsystem on the shuttle at KSC. The diagrams were referenced extensively by engineering and the Rocketdyne techs for Shuttle processing. In the engine Shop the diagrams were mounted all over the place. See:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/Shuttle_MPS_SSME_Tech_Meeting/wp_000114.jpg
[image]

I think a better version for you would be any of the following:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/ssme_block1.jpg
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/ssme_block1_2.jpg
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/SSME_Block1_3.jpg

[image]